# Flutter ListView.Builder Focus to Last Tile

Tags: dart, flutter

in this case I have a ListView.builder, and every time the page is called I intend to automatically listview the focus or scroll to the bottom list, this is my code:

```
return new ListView.builder(
        key: listViewKey,
        itemCount: chattile.length,

        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (chattile.length > 0) {
            if (chattile[index].from_id == "SystemDate" || chattile[index].from_id == "System") {
              return new SystemDate(chattile: chattile[index]);
            } else {
              if (chattile[index].from_id ==
                  "5a91687811138e74009839c9") {
                return new SendChat(chattile: chattile[index]);
              } else {
                return new ReceiveChat(chattile: chattile[index]);
              }
            }
          } else {
            return new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text('Tidak ada pesan.'),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        controller: ScrollController( //this is assumed to be null
            initialScrollOffset: 10000.0,
//            initialScrollOffset: context.size.height
        ),
      );
```

> s a note, I don't use the `reverse: true` attribute because it will
>   change the arrangement of my chat list.

I have searched for various sources but have not received the right answer, is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `animateTo(double offset, { Duration duration, Curve curve }) → Future<Null>` method in `ScrollController`. Offset can be context.size.height (Double.maximum might work)

Comment: where can i add your code to my code? can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

```
yourScrollController.animateTo(yourScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
```

You can use this func.